# how to use a simple way to determine the end of the streaming of client in asynchronous GRPC++?

Tags: c, grpc

Now I'm learning Bidirectional streaming in asynchronous GRPC++.
Thanks for the master:https://github.com/Mityuha/grpc_async. I get much useful information to know the  realization principle of this mode.But I have a question about it:
Not much to say,the code is following:
the server:

```
if(!ok || mcounter >= greeting.size())//ctx_.IsCancelled() doesn't work
    {
        std::cout << "[ProceedMM]: Trying finish" << std::endl;
        status_ = FINISH;
        responder_.Finish(Status(), (void*)this);
    }
```

the client:

```
void AsyncCompleteRpc()
    {
        void* got_tag;
        bool ok = false;
        while(cq_.Next(&got_tag, &ok))
        {
            AbstractAsyncClientCall* call = static_cast<AbstractAsyncClientCall*>(got_tag);
            call->Proceed(ok);
        }
        std::cout << "Completion queue is shutting down." << std::endl;
    }
```

in this server,the end of ClientStream is judged by the bool value of OK which is send by client.It isn't similar to the way of synchronous GRPC,which is judged the steaming end by the return of `bool Read(RequestType* request)` in the class of ServerReaderWriter in many times.It's so strange to find the same way in the class of ServerAsyncReaderWriter which is `void Read(R* msg, void* tag)`.Though I know it's because of the asynchronous way.But if I don't know how much times of asynchronous streaming without the judgement of "OK", how to find the way like synchronous streaming to judge the end of client streaming.Because I test the performance by java which is the same code between synchronous with asynchronous ways,which don't have the bool value of OK in asynchronous ways.
So can someone help me?Or tell me some ways to deal with it or find a way to test the performance testing of GRPC++ by Bazel of in my another question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I get the question, but what `ok` tells you is (when false) that the operation you requested couldn't be completed and nothing else will ever complete successfully on that side of the stream. So if you issue a `Read` operation and the `Next` gives you a `!ok` value, then you can be sure that no more data will ever come back from the client. A more detailed explanation is given in the comments for the `CompletionQueue` class.

Thanks and good luck with gRPC.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of receiving a stream in an asynchronous client of gRPC, you will use a `ClientAsyncReader<>` class to receive data. This class differs when both send and receive are stream, but logic is the same.

This class has a `Finish()` method which you need to call after finishing sending your rpc data to server. When answer stream from server is finished, a message to `CompletionQueue` will be added which corresponds to this method. This `Finish` method returns final status when **its message is returned in CQ**. You can find out that your stream is finished. Your code will be similar to this:

```
response_reader_ = stub->PrepareAsyncXYZ(ctx_, req, cq);
response_reader_->StartCall(&start_data_);
response_reader_->Finish(&status_, &finish_data_);
```

in this sample, message in CQ will have `finish_data_` tag and you can use it to handle it properly. You will probably will need to manage messages for `Finish()` and `Read()` by reference counting, because you will probably get an additional failed read message too. when message with `finish_data_` is received in CQ, `status_` will have the valid value of status.

At least it is how I wrote it.